# Decrypting plantext using HMAC of crypto++

Tags: c++, decode, hmac

I have a problem using HMAC of crypto++ library

I have used this link for making a encrypted message [crypto++-HMAC](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HMAC) and it works okay

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
SecByteBlock key(16);
prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
string plain = "HMAC Test";
string mac, encoded;
// Pretty print key
encoded.clear();
StringSource ss1(key, key.size(), true,
new HexEncoder(
    new StringSink(encoded)
) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource

cout << "key: " << encoded << endl;
cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

try
{
HMAC< SHA256 > hmac(key, key.size());

StringSource ss2(plain, true, 
    new HashFilter(hmac,
        new StringSink(mac)
    ) // HashFilter      
); // StringSource
}
catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
{
cerr << e.what() << endl;
exit(1);
}
// Pretty print
encoded.clear();
StringSource ss3(mac, true,
new HexEncoder(
    new StringSink(encoded)
) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource

cout << "hmac: " << encoded << endl;
```

now on the other side I want to decrypt this message and get the real plain Text
but I don't get any result yet .I've checked steps of this link [decode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder) but it didn't help me. I don't know where I should use Key?

please guide me through finding a solution

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve? HMAC uses an irreversible hash so it is not possible to decode back to the original message.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, many thanks for your comment, I want to use MAC for sending my messages and I found out that HMAC is provably secure . if HMAC is irreversible which member of MAC family I could use?

Comment: MAC stands for "message authentication code", it is for verifying a message has not been modified, you still need to transmit the message itself. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Comment: @AlanBirtles, now I understood

Comment: Look into AES encrypting for example. OpenSSL has some good explanation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I have another question , which part of message should be encoded for MAC?for example my message have time, data, sequence Number, src and destination id, thanks

Comment: @Clonk, thanks, I actually need to decode part of message instead of decrypting that

Comment: OpenSSL is a good point to start if you want to understand cryptography. Here are some links that have helped me  on similar topic : [HMAC example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying). [Digest example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests). [Symetric encryption/ decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that HMAC is not an encryption algorithm, It's an encoding algorithm.

others can see our messages using HMAC but they cannot give us messages which are unverified.

and all of message bytes can be encoded for sending and in receiver part we decode with our key and check authority of messages, encoded section of message has fix size according to hashing function that we use(MD5, SHA1, SHA256)